# How to use Every Proxy with WireGuard VPN?

Tags: vpn, wireguard

I'm trying to share my VPN connection from Android to a laptop.

**I've downloaded Every Proxy, set up proxy IP and port on the laptop and it works when VPN is off. Similarly, it doesn't work when Every Proxy is off. So on the proxy side everything looks ok.**

But once I turn VPN and Every Proxy on - my laptop loses internet connection.

The same thing happens both with WireGuard and Proton VPN.

I've edited WireGuard tunnel to add "Every Proxy" app to exclusions, then I get internet on my laptop, but with my native IP address - VPN is not active on laptop.

What am I missing?

The same issue with no solution I've found on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/r8ccj8/android_every_proxy_and_wireguard_vpn/).

Answer (score 1):

I was missing Every Proxy network bridge, which I had to install and to enable in the settings of the Every Proxy. The full instruction to follow is here:

https://www.everyproxy.co.uk/how-to-share-your-vpn-connection-over-https-with-other-devices